# I have a alphanumeric id. how do i auto increment(+1) the numbers?

Tags: c#, auto-increment

I have a alphanumeric id. how do i auto increment(+1) the numbers?

I'm supposed to set the Survey ID to SVY0001 to SVY9999.

How do i increase the numbers by 1 each time i add a new survey?

Currently i have a regular expression validator in my survey id text box for the SVY to be compulsary.

```
ValidationExpression="^SVY([0-9]{4})$"
```

Please advise me.

Here's my .cs code.

```
protected void btnCreateSurvey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    SqlCommand command = null;

    try
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SurveyFdDBConnString"].ConnectionString;
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        string sql = "Insert into Survey (SurveyID, SurveyName, CreatedBy, DateCreated, Anonymous) Values " + "(@SurveyID, @SurveyName, @CreatedBy, @DateCreated, @Anonymous)";
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurveyID", txtBoxSurveyID.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurveyName", txtBoxSurveyName.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", (string)Session["UserID"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCreated", DateTime.Now);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Anonymous", txtBoxAnonymous.Text);

        int rowCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rowCount != 0)
        {
            Session["SurveyID"] = txtBoxSurveyID.Text;
            Response.Write("Survey created successfully.<br/>");
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Select.aspx");
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }

    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        txtBoxSurveyID.Text = string.Empty;
        txtBoxSurveyName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtBoxAnonymous.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combined key for the primary key. In one column the alphanumeric code and in the other the number. In the integer column you can set as identity and sql does the job for you.

To set the combined key. Create the two columns, one integer and one varchar. Select one on the columns with shift down select the second and then select the button of the key in the menu to set them as the key.

Then go to properties > Identity column and select from the dropdown the integer column.

**Combined key example** after you select the key in the menu you will see both column with a key

[image]

**Select column as the identity example**

[image]

Comment: How do i set the combined key for the primary key? Sorry but I'm new to this. Do you mind explaining it further? With examples for me to refer to maybe? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If the `SVY` portion is just a prefix I would just store the integer and concatenate the prefix and integer for display purposes. It's not necessary to include it in the key if it's fixed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need the SVY to be in the database.

Answer (score 1):

1) Get the total row count from sql.

2) Inside `btnCreateSurvey_Click`, total row count + 1

3) `Session["SurveyID"] = txtBoxSurveyID.Text + totalRowCount.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'); //Assuming your textBoxSurvey ID is always "SVY"`

Comment: Hi we had this same problem and this approach, it works in the beginning but in occasions causes conflicts. You can't control that other record is created by other user when your code is making this calculation and inserting the record. Its better when the database take ownership of this problems.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by 'can't control that other record is created by other user'. If you are accessing the sql table which is referring to the survery form table, why would it be a problem?

Comment: @jhyap: Your solution has an implicit race condition.

Comment: For example just after you make the calculation of the row count other record is inserted the number will increase and your insert will fail.

Comment: I see. So what you mean is the database is updated by another user before the current user finish the click. If this application is used by multiple user at a time, then my solution is not a good solution :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class SurveyId
{
  static int counter = 0 ;
  static readonly object Syncroot = new object() ;

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format( "SVY{0:0000}" , this.Value )
  }

  public int Value { get ; private set ; }

  private SurveyId( int value )
  {
    this.Value = value ;
  }

  public static SurveyId GetNext()
  {
    lock ( Syncroot )
    {
      ++counter ;
    }
    return new SurveyId(counter) ;
  }

}
```

Though it has the problem that your survey IDs will restart from SVY0000 each time the app domain is recycled.

In your database, you can do this and let your database manage the survey IDs

```
create table dbo.survey
(
  id        int  not null identity(1,1) ,
  survey_id as 'SVY' + right('0000'+convert(varchar,id),4) ,
  name      varchar(255) not null ,
  -- other
  -- attributes
  -- here

  constraint Survey_PK primary key clustered ( id ) ,
  constraint Survey_AK01 unique nonclustered ( survey_id ) ,

)
```

Your insert statement then becomes something like

```
insert dbo.survey (name) values( 'foobar')
select scope_identity()
```

You'll need to use [`SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will return the value of the id column just inserted.